# How to share dynamic value from SherlockActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

My listview :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int position, long id) {

        UtamaBean mb = (UtamaBean) adapter
                .getItem(position);

        Intent in = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),
                DetailAct.class);

        in.putExtra(Constants.TAG_Title, mb.getTitle());
        in.putExtra(Constants.TAG_Created, mb.getCreated());
        in.putExtra(Constants.TAG_Img, mb.getImg());
        in.putExtra(Constants.TAG_Link, mb.getLink());
        in.putExtra(Constants.TAG_Post, mb.getPost());

        try {
            startActivityForResult(in, 500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

I want to use the data from `Intent in = getIntent();` and take its contents :

`String judul` , `String img` , `String tanggal` , `String desk` and `String link` .

```
public class DetailAct extends SherlockActivity {

    ImageLoader img_loader;
    ImageView imgPhoto = null;

    Typeface regular;
    Typeface medium;
    Typeface bold;
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.new_log);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "font/Alstom Regular.otf");
        medium = Typeface
                .createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Alstom Medium.otf");
        bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Alstom Bold.otf");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String NamaHari = "";

        if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Senin";
        else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Selasa";
        else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Rabu";
        else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Kamis";
        else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Jumat";
        else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Sabtu";
        else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek)
            NamaHari = "Minggu";

        final Date currentTime = new Date();
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

        // Give it to me in GMT time.
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));
        System.out.println("GMT time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));

        TextView strTanggal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        strTanggal.setText(NamaHari + ", " + sdf.format(currentTime));
        strTanggal.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        Intent in = getIntent();

        String judul = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Title);
        String img = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Img);
        String tanggal = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Created);
        String desk = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Post);
            String link = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Link);

        TextView lblJudul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strJUDUL);
        TextView lblTanggal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strTANGGAL);
        TextView lblDeskripsi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strDESK);

        img_loader = new ImageLoader(DetailAct.this);
        imgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strIMG);
        getImagesSize();

        try {
            if (img.length() > 0) {
                img_loader.DisplayImage(img, imgPhoto, 4);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        lblJudul.setTypeface(bold);
        lblTanggal.setTypeface(medium);
        lblDeskripsi.setTypeface(regular);
        strTanggal.setTypeface(medium);

        lblJudul.setText(judul);
        lblTanggal.setText(tanggal);
        lblDeskripsi.setText(desk);
    }

    private void getImagesSize() {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int w = dm.widthPixels;
        int h = dm.heightPixels;

        if (w <= 240 && h <= 320) {
            Constant.MAX_ThumbImage_SIZE = 100;
            Constant.MAX_Image_SIZE = 400;

        } else if (w <= 320 && h <= 480) {
            Constant.MAX_ThumbImage_SIZE = 100;
            Constant.MAX_Image_SIZE = 600;

        } else if (w <= 480 && h <= 854) {
            Constant.MAX_ThumbImage_SIZE = 150;
            Constant.MAX_Image_SIZE = 900;

        } else {
            Constant.MAX_ThumbImage_SIZE = 200;
            Constant.MAX_Image_SIZE = 1000;

        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(
                R.id.btn_share).getActionProvider();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "judul_HERE");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tanggal_HERE");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "link_HERE");
    return intent;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }

}
```

In this section :

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "judul_HERE");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tanggal_HERE");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "link_HERE");
return intent;
```

How i get all data from :

```
String judul = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Title);
String img = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Img);
String tanggal = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Created);
String desk = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Post);
String link = in.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Link);
```

Comment: you need to override `onActivityResult` an get the values there. Also where is  `setResult(RESULT_OK,in)` in `DetailActivity` coz you are using `startActivityForResult`

Comment: @Raghunandan Where do I have to put `setResult(RESULT_OK,in)` ? For this case all has gone well in the casting to the TextView all the data has been performing well on the screen. It's just when they want to take the data to be shared to facebook using `ShareActionProvider` are still not able to capture the data.

Comment: i am confused when you click list item you `startActivityForResult`. In DetailActivity where do you get that data? and in the listview activity where do you override `onActivityResult`

Comment: How do I fix the script? I get this source of examples of what I get. If the use of `startActivityForResult` is not supposed to be like that, to be replaced in a way that is like what? When i use `Intent in = getIntent();` in DetailActivity, the data I get smoothly

Comment: ok that should work for getting the values in DetailActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
**DetailAct you send your dynamic data back to SherlockActivity like this way**
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SherlockActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "judul_HERE");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tanggal_HERE");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "link_HERE");
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
}

**SherlockActivity you get data from DetailAct like this way**
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==500){
            String judul = data.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Title);
            String img = data.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Img);
            String tanggal = data.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Created);
            String desk = data.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Post);
            String link = data.getStringExtra(Constants.TAG_Link);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hai @Haresh `private Intent getDefaultShareIntent()` must have `return intent` right?